# AngularJS reload service when network status Offline

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework, service

I need you help.

I am trying to refresh a service in case there is no network. When it's OFFLINE, it works. But when it returns to ONLINE status, it loses the internal code when it returns a success result.

This happens because at first there was no network and it failed, which causes the internal code not to run.

The code in controller.js is:

```
.controller('Home', function($scope, $state, Service_Caller) {
    var url = "http://localhost:8080/getUsers";

    Service_Caller.get(url, "GET", Service_Caller).then(function(resp) { 
      // return this is status network is online.
      // in case offline, when refresh service again and network return online, service return response but this line not run.
      console.log(resp); 
    });
})
```

service.js

```
.factory('Service_Caller', function($http, $ionicPopup, $rootScope) {
    return {
    get: function (url_call, method, tryagain) {
        return $http({
              method: method,
              url: url_call,
              headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
            }).success(function(response){

                //****** if ONLINE! *******
                return response.data;

            }).error(function(err, status){

                //****** if OFFLINE! *******

                if(status == 0 || status == 502){
                  var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                    title: "Error",
                    template: '<div class="col-100 text-center">No hay conexión de internet</div>',
                    buttons: [{
                      text: '<i class="ion-android-hand"></i>&nbsp;Cancelar',
                      type: 'button-default',
                      onTap: function(e) {
                        return false;
                      }
                    }, { 
                      text: '<i class="ion-android-refresh"></i>&nbsp;Refrescar',
                      type: 'button-assertive',
                      onTap: function(e) {

                        // execute again service.
                        tryagain.get(url_call, method, tryagain);

                      }
                    }]
                  });
                }

            });
        }
    }
})
```

Any idea how I can call the service again and return the response when the network is restored?

Answer (score 0):

run the below commands

```
npm install ngCordova
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information
```

Add the script refrences in index.html for ngCordova

Inject $cordovaNetwork into your factory

```
.factory('Service_Caller',
 function($http, $ionicPopup, $rootScope, $cordovaNetwork) {
    return {
    get: function (url_call, method, tryagain) {
        var isOnline = $cordovaNetwork.isOnline();
        var isOffline = $cordovaNetwork.isOffline();
        var errorHandler=function(){
            if(status == 0 || status == 502){
                      var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
                        title: "Error",
                        template: '<div class="col-100 text-center">No hay conexión de internet</div>',
                        buttons: [{
                          text: '<i class="ion-android-hand"></i>&nbsp;Cancelar',
                          type: 'button-default',
                          onTap: function(e) {
                            return false;
                          }
                        }, { 
                          text: '<i class="ion-android-refresh"></i>&nbsp;Refrescar',
                          type: 'button-assertive',
                          onTap: function(e) {

                            // execute again service.
                            tryagain.get(url_call, method, tryagain);

                          }
                        }]
                      });
                    }
            }

            if($cordovaNetwork.isOnline())
            {

                $http({
                      method: method,
                      url: url_call,
                      headers: {'Accept': 'application/json'}
                    }).success(function(response){

                        return response.data;

                    }).error(function(err, status){
                        errorHandler();
                        //****** if OFFLINE! *******
                    });
            }
            else
            {
                errorHandler();
            }
        }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I use straight cordova plugin and there is two methods you can use:

**Method 1**
Install the plugin

> $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-dialogs

Then add the code to your service:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);
  function onOffline() {

    function onDismissed() {
      navigator.app.exitApp();
      //or do other things
    }

    navigator.notification.alert(
      'Netowrk Error',
      onDismissed,
      'Network error message',
      'OK'
    );
  }
}, false);
```

**Method 2**
Install the plugin

> $ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-network-information

Then add the code to your service:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
  document.addEventListener("offline", onOffline, false);

  function onOffline() {
      // Handle the offline event
  }

  document.addEventListener("online", onOnline, false);

  function onOnline() {
      // Handle the offline event
  }
}, false);
```